# Obtener listas en python

Tags: python, lista, funciones, bucle-for

mi código:

```
lista1 = [['casa',1,8,True,'casa', 'puerta'],['arbol', 'perro', 9986, 'xs86d'],['portatil', taza', 9776, 'hdge6dy', 'cascos']]

for i in lista1:
  for n in indx:
    print(n[i])
```

lo que obtengo con este código es todos los elementos indexados por indx dentro de de las listas anidadas , lo que me gustaria obtener es una lista con los elementos de la primera lista y otra lista con los elementos de la segunda y asi con todas.
he intentando esto:

```
for i in lista1:
  for n in indx:
     a.append(n[i])
```

pero obtengo una lista con los elementos de cada lista.

Comment: Qué es records?

Comment: me he equivocado, ya  esta arreglado.

Comment: Tu quieres de lista1 mostrar la primera lista?

Comment: no, lo acabo de aclarar, perdón, lo que quiero es una lista de los elementos seleccionados, otra lista distinta con los elementos de la segunda y así con todas las listas anidadas.

Comment: O sea una lista aparte por cada lista dentro de lista1?

Comment: si, el output serían varias listas y cada lista tendría los elementos seleccionados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas crear una lista auxiliar en la que meterás los elementos que te indique `indx`, y después metes esa lista auxiliar en la lista `a` que estás construyendo. Es decir:

```
indx=[0,1]
lista1 = [['casa', 1, 8, True, 'casa', 'puerta'],
          ['arbol', 'perro', 9986, 'xs86d'],
          ['portatil', 'taza', 9776, 'hdge6dy', 'cascos']]

a = []
for sublista in lista1:
  aux = []
  for n in indx:
    aux.append(sublista[n])
  a.append(aux)
```

El resultado es (espero) lo que buscas:

```
[['casa', 1], ['arbol', 'perro'], ['portatil', 'taza']]
```

Esto se puede acortar si usas una *comprensión de listas* para hacer la auxiliar:

```
a = []
for sublista in lista1:
  aux = [ sublista[n] for n in indx]
  a.append(aux)
```

De hecho podemos ahorrar la variable `aux` y meter directamente la comprensión de listas dentro de `a`:

```
a = []
for sublista in lista1:
  a.append([ sublista[n] for n in indx])
```

Es más, podemos usar también una comprensión de listas para crear `a` (esta comprensión usaría dentro otra comprensión). Esto dejaría el programa en una sola línea:

```
a = [ [sublista[n] for n in indx] for sublista in lista1]
```

Comment: No sabia que se podia utilizar listas auxiliares, es lo que estaba buscando muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
indx=[0,1]
lista1 = [['casa',1,8,True,'casa', 'puerta'],['arbol', 'perro', 9986, 'xs86d'],['portatil', 'taza', 9776, 'hdge6dy', 'cascos']]

size= len(lista1)
    
for i in range(size):
    print("lista"+str(i));
    for element in lista1[i]:
        if(lista1[i].index(element) in indx):
            print(element)
```

Comment: Aclaro hace mucho qué no toco python, tampoco sé si es lo qué buscabas pero al menos tienes una idea

Comment: vale, gracias. me devolvía esto: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(lista1+i);
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: Es qué no se pueden concatenar ints con Strings, ya cambié el código

Comment: Igual ojo, escríbelo bien creo qué escribiste mal en el print

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    if(index(element) in indx):
NameError: name 'index' is not defined

Comment: eso me ha salido. muchas gracias igualmente

Comment: lo que viene a comentarte Belgica, como es un array multidimensional, para obtener la lista de elementos del "subbarray" que hay dentro de cada posicion del array principal, solo tienes que poner el nombre del array principal y la posicion que ocupa el subarray que quieras rescatar en el array principal por ejemplo lista1[0] , lista1[1]  , y si quieres acceder a un valor del subarray tendrias colocar la posicion del array principal y la del subarray por ejemplo, ...... lista1l[0][0], lista1[0][1],lista1[0][2]

Comment: Si, ya he actualizado el código, no sé si era es lo qué quería lograr. En tal caso perdón por no poder ayudar.